# Regarding Backup While Using CP

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, backup

I have some files on the Desktop

```
/Desktop/F1/T1 
/Desktop/F2/T2
```

I want to copy those files to another folder like `Destination`
but If the destination contains a file with same name I want to backup it to a folder named `/Backup`

So if a file named `/Desktop/F1/T1` Already Exist on `/Destination/F1/T1` it should be moved as
`Backup/F1/T1` 
I Need a Linux Script for this *(actually Unix)*,
The Command `cp -b` doesn't work on Mac.

Comment: Anything that you have tried ?

Comment: This is very basic, at least try something yourself. This isn't a script request service!

Answer (score 0):

Try rsync with the `--backup` and `--backup-dir` flags.

Answer (score 0):

`cp -n` doesn't overwrite files that already exist.

```
cd ~/Desktop/
cp -Rn * ~/Destination/
cp -R * ~/Backup/
```